# пытаюсь дать название кнопкам по индексу, не выходит (17 строчка с верху) на js

Tags: javascript

```js
let row2 = document.getElementById('row2');
let divu = document.createElement('div');
divu.className = "uslugi";
divu.style.textAlign = "center"
row2.appendChild(divu);
let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
h2.innerHTML = "Услуги";
divu.style.margin = "auto";
divu.style.width = "610px";
divu.appendChild(h2);
let divub = document.createElement('div');
divub.className = "buttons"
row2.appendChild(divub)
divu.appendChild(divub)
h2.style.textAlign = "center"
for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let form = document.createElement('form')
    divub.append(form)
    let btns = document.createElement('button')
    btns.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btns.className = "btn btn-primary";
    form.appendChild(btns);
 }
    form.children[0].innerHTML = "Хирургия<br>удвление зубов"
    form.children[1].innerHTML = "Имплантация зубов<br>протезирование на имплантах"
    form.children[2].innerHTML = "Лечение парадонтоза<br>на аппарате 'вектор'"
    form.children[3].innerHTML = "Шинирование зубов"
    form.children[4].innerHTML = "Все виды работ"
    form.children[5].innerHTML = "Рестоврация зубов"
    form.children[6].innerHTML = "Лечение от кариеса до пульпита"
    form.children[7].innerHTML = "Зуботехническая лаборотория"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
const buttonsTitles = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const $body = document.querySelector('body');

for (let title of buttonsTitles) {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
  button.innerHTML = title;
  $body.append(button)
}
```

Comment: Только, создать div его куда-то запушить, а в него запушить кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Cоздать массив названий и по нему цикл делать

```js
for(index in buttonsTitles) {
    form.children[index].innerHTML = buttonsTitles[index]
 }
```

Comment: А зачем вы форму создаете и в нее кнопки кладете?

Comment: Nikita, а что посоветуете? я только недавно начал изучать js, решил начать с dom

Comment: форму можно использовать, если нужно отправить запрос на сервер. Вам же это совсем здесь не нужно. Просто положите в div их какой-нибудь.

Comment: Примерно так:
```js
```

Comment: Nikita, но так ведь из кнопки ссылку не создать. скажем form action=index2.html и внутри формы уже кнопки

Comment: Создайте ссылку, запушьте в нее кнопку

Comment: Я проверил, все ок

Comment: Будьте добры, если я помог вам, отметить мой ответ полезным :)